# C: gets() skips the first input

Tags: c, string, input, gets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


typedef struct record
{   
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char telephone[20];

}Record;

typedef struct node
{
    Record data;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;

void addRecord(Record s)
{
    Node *newNode;
    Node *n;

    newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = s;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        // The linked list is empty
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        // Traverse the whole list until we arrive at the last node
        n = head;
        while (n->next != NULL)
        {
            n = n->next;
    }
        n->next = newNode;
    }
}

Record enterRecordDetails()
{
    Record aRecord;
    int len;
    int valid = 0;
    int valid2 = 0;
    printf("ENTER THE FOLLOWING RECORD DETAILS:\n");

    printf("   NAME      : ");
    gets(aRecord.name);
    printf("   SURNAME   : ");
    gets(aRecord.surname);  
    do {
        valid = 0;
        valid2 = 0;
        printf("  TELEPHONE NO. (8 digits): ");
        gets(aRecord.telephone);
        len = strlen(aRecord.telephone);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (!isdigit(aRecord.telephone[i])) {
                printf("You enterred an invalid number\n");
                valid = 1; break;
            }
        }
        Node *p = head;         
            while (p != NULL)
            {
                Node *next = p->next;
                for (; next; p = next, next = next->next) {
                    if (strcmp(p->data.telephone, aRecord.telephone) == 0)
                    {
                        valid2 = 1; break;
                    }
                }
                if(p = NULL)break;
            }

    } while((valid == 1) || (len != 8) || (valid2 == 1));
    getchar();
    fflush(stdin);
    return aRecord;
}


int main(void)
{
    char menuOption;

    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("~~~ MAIN MENU ~~~\n");
        printf("1. Add Telephone Record\n");
        printf("2. Delete Telephone Record\n");
        printf("3. Search\n");
        printf("4. Display All Records\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n\n");
        menuOption = getchar();
        fflush(stdin);
        switch (menuOption)
     {
    case '1':
        addRecordToList();
        break;
    case '4':
        displayList();
        break;
    }

} while (menuOption != '5');

getchar();
return 0;
```

}

When adding a student, the computer asks the user to enter the surname rather than the name. Why is the program skipping 'Name' ?  'Name' is displayed, however the user is expected to write the surname instead.

Comment: You have posted only part of your program. That's not very helpful to diagnose the problem. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should not use `gets`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used.

Comment: The problem is the interaction of `gets()` with previous, unposted code.

Comment: C programming language does not have `gets`

Comment: also your problem could probably be fixed by adding `fflush(stdout)` before reading the input.

Comment: `gets` is not part of the C standard (anymore) and should **never** be used. And you are supposed to enable warnings and check for relevant errors from functions before asking. Your code does not.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour. And `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char` on purpose.

Comment: Which compiler (and version) are you using? It might be useful to add a tag for this, to stop all these "today C means strict standard C11" comments (which *are* kinda valid, even if a bit nitpicky).

Comment: Its that `getchar();`, it is messing up things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not use `gets`, it's unsafe. Use [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) instead.

The reason why the first call to `gets` skips a line is that there is a `'\n'` in the buffer at the time that you are making a call to `enterRecordDetails()`. Typically, the `'\n'` is a leftover from an earlier input operation, for example, from reading an `int` with `scanf`.

One way to fix this problem is to read the string to the end when reading the `int`, so that the consecutive call of `fgets` would get the actual data. You can do it in your `enterRecordDetails()` function:

```
Record enterRecordDetails()
{
    Record aRecord;
    printf("ENTER THE FOLLOWING RECORD DETAILS:\n");
    printf("   NAME      : ");
    fscanf(stdin, " "); // Skip whitespace, if any
    fgets(aRecord.name, 20, stdin);
    printf("   SURNAME   : ");
    fgets(aRecord.surname, 20, stdin);  
}
```

Note, however, that `fgets` keeps `'\n'` in the string, as long as it fits in the buffer. A better approach would be using `scanf`, and passing a format specifier that limits the length of input and stops at `'\n'`:

```
scanf(" %19[^\n]", aRecord.name);
//     ^
```

Comment: `scanf("%19[^\n]", aRecord.surname);` reads nothing into `aRecord.surname` if the first character is `'\n'`, leaving it uninitialized and the offending `'\n'` in `stdin`.  This would certainly happen as a previous `scanf("%19[^\n]", aRecord.name);` does not consume the `'\n'`.  Best to use `fgets()`.

Comment: @chux My only reservation about `fgets` is its keeping the `\n` in my string. Of course it's easy to get rid of that string, but it's better to not have it there in the first place.

Comment: I disagree is is _easier_ using `scanf()` and not get the `'\n'` than `fgets()`.  YMMV.

Comment: Basically the only way to do sensible line-based input in C is to write your own function for it, which does it the way you want (using `fgets` or `scanf` or `getchar` or whatever internally). If you use `scanf` or `fgets` directly, your code gets cluttered with error, long line and buffer size handling (or, more commonly, these aren't really handled, and things go haywire on unexpected input). Or just use [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) if you are programming for recent POSIX or GNU OS...

Comment: @chux You are right, this would mess up the prompts. I agree with hyde, by the way, that if one wants to do it right, he needs to do it himself, i.e. use `fgets` to read line-by-line, and then parse the data manually.

Comment: Agree with you and @hyde.  User input is _evil_ and needs handling better than direct use of C standard input functions.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Why Did You Left a space before "  %19[^\n]"